# How to Python Pandas Dataframe outputs from nested json?

Tags: python, mysql, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm python beginner.
Those below 'steps_detail' data is like that;

```
>>> steps_detail
{u'activities-calories': 
    [{u'value': u'1240', u'dateTime': u'2015-04-13'}],
    u'activities-calories-intraday': 
        {u'datasetType': u'minute', u'datasetInterval': 1, u'dataset': 
        [
        {u'mets': 10, u'time': u'00:00:00', u'value': 0.8396000266075134, u'level': 0}, 
        {u'mets': 10, u'time': u'00:01:00', u'value': 0.8396000266075134, u'level': 0}, 
        {u'mets': 10, u'time': u'00:02:00', u'value': 0.8396000266075134, u'level': 0},
        {u'mets': 10, u'time': u'23:58:00', u'value': 0.8396000266075134, u'level': 0}, 
        {u'mets': 10, u'time': u'23:59:00', u'value': 0.8396000266075134, u'level': 0}
         ]      
        }
}
```

And I want to see this data using DataFrame of pandas like that; because I will using this data to save mysql.

```
mets time       value              level
10   00:00:00   0.8396000266075134  0 
10   00:01:00   0.8396000266075134  0 
10   00:02:00   0.8396000266075134  0
10   23:58:00   0.8396000266075134  0 
10   23:59:00   0.8396000266075134  0
```

It's not easy to me, and anyone has some idea? I'm just trying, but some error.

```
>>>d= DataFrame(steps_detail)
raise ValueError('Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to 'ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Comment: Could you try [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(steps_detail['activities-calories-intraday']['dataset'])
```

this will return you the following output

```
    level  mets      time   value
0      0    10  00:00:00  0.8396
1      0    10  00:01:00  0.8396
2      0    10  00:02:00  0.8396
3      0    10  23:58:00  0.8396
4      0    10  23:59:00  0.8396
```